# Need help in SQL query in Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I need help in writing a T-SQL query, where I have to add all the AD Group members in the output.

From below query I am getting this result.

```
SELECT dp.name AS UserX
    ,db_name() dbname
    ,dp.type_desc
FROM sys.database_role_members drm
LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON dp.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id
LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals dpr ON dpr.principal_id = drm.role_principal_id
WHERE dp.type_desc <> 'SQL_USER'
    AND dpr.name <> 'db_datareader'
```

**Output from the above query**

[image]

Instead of showing AD Group Names, I want the output showing the names present in that AD Group.

[image]

**I want the output as:**

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I don't think that info is available. AFAIK when someone logs in using Windows Credentials or Azure AD, the server attempts to match against a group via the domain controller. The data is simply not available without resorting to external tools